# No sound on laptop built-in speaker but headphone works

Tags: 12.04

As the title says,after finnished one regular update that pops out by the update manager, my laptop speakers fails to work. After reading the threats i can find online i find out that my alsamixer shows "This sound device does not have any controls.  " and i don't know what this indicates. Help needed (plz ignore my poor language)

Answer (score 0):

chek this https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/ and for more completed installations you can following this http://www.webupd8.org/2013/03/install-pulseaudio-with-built-in-system.html